# Uncrustify collapses multiple white spaces inside statement

Tags: c++, uncrustify

I wonder if there is a way to ask [uncrustify](http://uncrustify.sourceforge.net/) to leave aligning spaces inside statements, so that a group of functions calls get properly aligned like:

```
if (a)           f(5);
if (a && b)      f(6);
if (c)           f(7);
if (a && b && c) f(8);
```

With the default configuration file, I get:

```
if (a) f(5);
if (a && b) f(6);
if (c) f(7);
if (a && b && c) f(8);
```

Is that possible?

Comment: I don't think uncrustify looks at blocks of code like that to analyze the alignments.  This is a typical problem in all source formatters.  One way of 'fixing' it is to decide that 'proper alignment' is the version it gets revised to, or the variant with the functions calls on the line after the `if (condition)`.

Comment: The way to do it is to fork and hack!